# Predefined text in gedit using a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

To make my life easier I wanted to write a bash script that takes me to a predefined directory and makes a c file with user given file name.

I accomplished this with the following -

```
 #!/bin/bash
 cd ~/cs/graphs
gedit $(zenity --entry --title="File Name" --text="Enter file name.").c
```

Now I want gedit to contain some predefined text like the programmer's name, date from the system and standard library import lines.

Is it possible to do it through the script itself ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to grab the filename from the user before opening it in gedit. Echo the text that you want to the file, then open it with gedit:

```
#!/bin/bash
fname="$(zenity --entry --title="File Name" --text="Enter file name.").c"
file_text="Hello!
This is some text
that we will add 
to the file."

printf %s "$file_text" > "$fname"

gedit "$fname"
```

## Explanation

- First, store the output of zenity into fname
- Create a string that you want to print into the file.
- Print it into the file
- Open file with gedit.

I tested this script and it works.

Comment: I'd recommend doing `printf %s "$file_text" at least, in case `file_text` ends up including format strings or the like (e.g., if `file_text="my favorite is %s"`)

Comment: Eric, you make a great point. I have included your suggestion into an edit.

Comment: It might also be good to run `gedit` in the background with `&`.